# Google AppEngine Datastore Bulkloader behind http proxy

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

Is it possible to configure a http proxy (host and credentials) to be used by the bulkloader?

Answer (score 0):

BulkLoader uses httplib which uses the environment variables http_proxy, you can try to set the value to http://username:password@proxy_url:port